# Switch speed and Router speed

Tags: switch, router

All my computers (+ NAS, etc) are connected to a gigabit switch and they all have gigabit ethernet controllers.

The switch is connected to a Cisco RV110W router (10/100) which also serves as DHCP server, firewall and gateway to internet.

If I switch to a gigabit Cisco RV130W router will I see an increase in transfer speeds between computers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. When you are transferring data between computers on your local LAN that data is only traversing the gig E switch you speak of and doesn't touch the router.

Comment: Unless the computers are on different subnets or vlans.

Comment: They are all on the same subnet.